# Why should I avoid using Java Label Statements?

Tags: java, nested-loops, break, continue, labeled-statements

Everywhere across the internet people say that you should avoid using label statements in java. However, I find them very useful in some cases, namely nested loops.
I cannot find satisfactory answers as to why not to use them. I think that alternatives to labels often reduce either readability, or performance, or both.

So what makes labeled break and continue statements so bad?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate. Check <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496/should-i-avoid-using-java-label-statements">this</a>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496/

Comment: I think this would be a much more interesting discussion if you provided some code showing a, in your oppinion, just case for using a label.

Comment: No reason at all. When you need them, you need them. Probably some trace of *goto*-aversion, but not really related.

Answer (score 8):

Labels are perfectly okay to break out of nested for-loops.

PS: *personally, I'd suggest (and I am in accordance with Kent Beck on this, see his [implementation patterns](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321413091) book) to put the nested loops in a separate method and then break out with `return` but that will cast the anger of the "single return point" folks upon me. Internet, oh, internet.*

Comment: +1 for good advice and especially for scorn on religious nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I find both labelled breaks and continue statements to be completely unnecessary.  It's just a style thing.  There are other ways to achieve the same results and many people prefer those.

Answer (score 1):

Most common argument is that they're hard to interpret for starters. Another argument is that (too many) nested loops are considered bad practice; in other words, when you see a label, then there's almost certain a nested loop and that makes the label thus implicitly bad. Common practice is that nested loops are refactored into a method. This should improve maintainability and other things like that. However, if the nested loop isn't doing other things than the obvious thing in only a few lines of code, then it's in my opinion perfectly affordable.

Answer (score 0):

No need to avoid labels as long as the method does just one thing, one thing only and does it well.

However, if there is a need for labelled breaks and continue statements just do a quick mental check if the method is still cohesive enough.