# The program do not stop(to receive string) at expected point

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Power1Eng {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x, prod = 1;
        int n;
        String s;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("This program prints x(x is a real number) raised to the power of n(n is an integer).\n");

        outer_loop:
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Input x and n: ");
            x = input.nextDouble();
            n = input.nextInt();

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                prod *= x;
            }

            System.out.printf("%.1f raised to the power of %d is %.4f. Do you want to continue?(Y/N) ", x, n, prod);
            s = input.nextLine();

            if (s.equals("Y"))
                continue;
            else if (s.equals("N"))
                break;
            else {
                inner_loop:
                while (true) {
                    System.out.print("Wrong input. Do you want to continue?(Y/N) ");
                    s = input.nextLine();

                    if (s.equals("Y"))
                        continue outer_loop;
                    else if (s.equals("N"))
                        break outer_loop;
                    else
                        continue inner_loop;
                }   
            }   
        }       
    }

}
```

[image]

Look at the Console. In the third line, I expected the program prints until the first 'Do you want to continue?(Y/N)', but it also prints 'Wrong input. Do you want to continue?(Y/N)'. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your java has a very very VERY bad style. You should not use tags and jump-tos, they make code unreadable.
You should read the coding conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: Please please please remove those `continue` and `break` to labels! This java equivalent of goto should NEVER be necessary

Comment: NCode I agree my code is bad because I started to study java only a week ago!

Answer (score 1):

When you do the `nextInt` and `nextDouble`, it doesn't clear the (empty) rest of the line.

You need to call `nextLine` after reading these values to clear the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%.1f raised to the power of %d is %.4f. Do you want to continue?(Y/N) \n", x, n, prod);
s = input.next();
```

That will solve your problem and also do not use labels.

[Should I avoid using Java Label Statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496/should-i-avoid-using-java-label-statements)

People who get to maintain that code will find you.