# What's the equivalent for C#'s goto statement in Java?

Tags: java, android, goto

Is there a way I could adopt the C#'s goto statement in Java?

Comment: Please give an example of what you want to achieve. Even in C#, it's almost always better to avoid `goto` statements.

Comment: You need to be more clear what you want to do.. There are many who know Java but not C#..

Comment: I also agree with @JonSkeet wt is your issue?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java

Comment: i want to implement a TCP connection so incase there is an exception occured or disconnection i need to catch the exception and then re-establish a connection.

Comment: Its so simple then put your connection code in one function and call that function when you got exception !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a goto statement in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are named blocks, and you can have a labeled `break` statement:

```
loop: 
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      break loop;
```

Or

```
label: {
       if(something) 
          break label;
}
```

More information can be found in *[Branching Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)*. But other than that, you don't have a real goto statement.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct equivalent to the goto concept in Java. **You can use break and continue** .

Look at [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ305_024.htm) for labelled statements with break and continue.

Comment: Many random downvotes on java answers today... I just got two on this question too...

Comment: Yes. I want my answer to be chosen.

Comment: @user1581900 Its very silly reason. You can not dowvote any user answer to choose your answer as accepted .

Comment: @user1581900 Please use downvoting only for answers that are wrong or do not answer the question - not because you want to "win".

Comment: @user1581900 lol, thats nuts. Probably better to just write the best answer quickest and play fair. Otherwise you'll soon lose friends.

Comment: user1581900 can't be the only one downvoting or he has greater powers than me. I suppose his comment was a joke or badly phrased.

Comment: Successful troll is a happy troll. I already feel like I won and I'm much better now. Thank you. I needed it today. You can always downvote my answer - try it - it feels MUCH better then upvoting.

Comment: I'll upvote for no other reason than that you were downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

There is [no goto statement in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7):

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement.

The closest you have are `continue` and `break` statements, which can be used in combination with labels, to exit from a loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact equivalent but Java took care of the most legitimate use case, that is when you want to go to some label from inside a loop. In this case you may use break :

```
outerLoop:
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t = A[[i]][j];
    for (int z = 0; z < l; z++) {
        if (arrays[z].contains(t)) {
            continue outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

See also the examples in [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Labelled statements** with break and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Read about using label statements in Java.

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496/should-i-avoid-using-java-label-statements)

[flow control](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/flow/labels.html)

Answer (score -3):

> is there a way I could adopt the C#'s goto statement in JAVA?

The goto statement in java is a reserved keyword. However it is not implemented in any way. Probably there were plans to include it in the java engine.

To answer your question. You can used [labeled break](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), which works very similarly to goto:

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                 j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor +
                               " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor +
                               " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

Similar question was aswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430782/alternative-to-goto-statement-in-java)

Comment: When you take an example from another answer or an official Oracle tutorial, it's better to include the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).