# How to jump over a particular set of statements in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Try {


public static void main(String[] args) {
int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        if (i==6)
        {
            // The Execution pointer should go back to this statement (int i=0);
        }
        i++;
    }

}
}
```

We use `goto` keyword in VB to put the execution pointer  on particular set of statements. Please tell me How this is possible in Java. How we can place the execution pointer on particular set of statements?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java.It may help you

Comment: While most people will suggest using `continue` I prefer to ask why to have such odd design, is a good valid reason to use this? If so, please explain.

Comment: I am completely agree with @LuiggiMendoza. Furthermore, if you jump to `int i=0;`. program execution will enter `while` loop again and again which will make an infinite loop. That is why you should not use unconditional jumps. It is harder to predict program execution.

Answer (score 5):

`goto` was removed in Java so you can't use that. You will have to use `continue` or `break`.

Please don't really do this though. Properly designed code doesn't need to jump to specific lines in code. When I was starting to program in my early teens, goto was an easy crutch in BASIC, but it's still a crutch.

Read this as well: [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.4846&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: `goto` was removed? 
included as keyword and used for future purpose

Comment: @ajduke it was included in the first version of Java, then removed but the `goto` statement remains as keyword but does nothing.

Comment: It was removed as a valid function but still exists as a keyword.

Comment: ohk, never knew that.

Comment: `goto` is considered harmful only by people who fail to understand how to use it properly... In Java though it has little use (there are labeled statements, which does have uses)

Comment: @fge currently `goto` isn't implemented in Java, is maintained as keyword but doesn't work (see comments above)...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a labelled `continue` , but it is a bad practice though to write spaghetti code .

```
somepoint: { int i=0;
while(i<10)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    if (i==6)
    {
       continue somepoint;
    }
    i++;
}
}
```

Read [JLS 14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) for *Labelled Statements*.

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement; identifier statement labels are used with break (§14.15) or continue (§14.16) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

The [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

As per [JLS 3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs.

Also read [Should I avoid using Java Label Statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496/should-i-avoid-using-java-label-statements)

Comment: This code involves an infinite loop, but it is a good answer to OP's question.

Comment: @erencan IMO an answer that tries to solve a bad design with another bad design can't be considered as good =\

Comment: +1 @erencan I agree with the `infinite` loop .

Comment: This doesn't compile..

Comment: @Vulcan sorry forgot to add the block , i didn't test it though !

Comment: With the block, it simply breaks out of the labeled block rather than continue infinitely.  I've already written and tested the exact same code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is not a consultancy site ! A simple question with simple answer with pointers to what is not correct . I don't police over OP's design problems , if he has one he will get back to us . First aid is mandatory when there is a casualty , you can report the accident to the police later :)

Comment: @TheNewIdiot IMO giving a simple *use `continue`* advice is easy (otherwise look at all the other answers), but giving a solution to the real problem: **bad design** is what **we professional software engineers must do**, otherwise we are simply monkey programmers. By the way, your answer proposes that even having a simple scenario like this, you should use a `continue` statement instead of a `while(true)` to write an infinite loop (which is even a worse design).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza +1 I agree with your point but I am not a professional s/w engineer :)

Comment: That would explain the bad design you propose...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I **didn't propose any design** , the OP wanted to know *is there a way to do it* , I just hinted a way .

Answer (score 0):

Java has standard keyword for that:

```
break;
```

will exit cycle.

```
continue;
```

will jump to the start of the cycle.
Also, if you have "cycle inside cycle situation", you can use labels.

```
label1: while(true){
    ...
    label2: while(true){
        ...
        break label2;
        ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `goto` in java. You can achieve this by

```
i=0;
while(i<10)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    if (i==6)
    {
        i=0;
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public class Try {


   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int i=0;
   while(i<10)
   {
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    if (i==6)
    {
      i=0;
      continue;  // The Execution pointer should go back to this statement (int i=0);
    }
    i++;
    }

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about continue statement here is explanation of [The continue Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code will not move the pointer to `int i=o`, it will move to the while loop only.
2. And it will go to infinite loop, since you added `i=o in if(i==6)` condition.

So it is completely wrong.