# find 'fragmentary' subarray within an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I can find if a list's elements are sequentially within other lists (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425820/elegant-way-to-find-contiguous-subarray-within-an-array-in-javascript)), but am having trouble with some 'messy' data.

For example:

```
var source = ['the', 'dog', 'therefore', 'he', 'gets', 'a', 'treat'];
var search = ['there', 'fore', 'gets', 'treat']
```

There are two ways this query data is 'messy'.  First, some of the search terms have been separated (`'there', 'fore'`).  Second, some characters are omitted(`'he', 'a'`).

How to find the starting and ending index of the 'messy' search list members in the source list? (in my example above, I would want to get back `[2,6]` which corresponds to `therefore`@ 2 and `treat` @ 6 in the `source` list).

---

```
Your problem is underspecified.
What's the result for source = ['a', 'aa', 'a', 'b', 'a']], 
search = ['a', 'a']? Is it [0, 4] or [0, 2] or [1, 1] or ...? 
You could e.g. ask for the first, longest matching 'messy' subsequence. – le_m
```

Good point and good question.  I only need to skip single elements when searching `source`, and would want to get back the first match (and could extend the function to include a starting index in search).

Comment: is this javascript or python? Why both?

Comment: So essentially, you're asking to check whether two arrays are the same or not? Just run a `foreach` loop to check each element in `search` against each element in `source` for a direct match. Inside of the loop you can log the position that it doesn't match at.

Comment: @ObsidianAge `search`'s elements do not appear in sequence in `source`.  Asking for help in handling missing elements (`he`,`a`) and elements in `source` split into two elements in `search`.

Comment: Your problem is underspecified. What's the result for `source = ['a', 'aa', 'a', 'b', 'a']], search = ['a', 'a']`? Is it `[0, 4]` or `[0, 2]` or `[1, 1]` or ...? You could e.g. ask for the first, longest matching 'messy' subsequence.

Comment: The criteria is not clear. Can you please describe it again `[2,6]` corresponds to `therefore` & `treat` right?

Answer (score 1):

Going to make some assumptions:

The values in `search` are unique so no `['treat', 'treat']`

The values in `source` are also unique.

As far as effectiveness/efficiency I can't really help you there. I hope this gives you a good idea of how to start.

```js
var source = ['the', 'dog', 'therefore', 'he', 'gets', 'a', 'treat'];
var search = ['there', 'fore', 'gets', 'treat'];


let start, finish;
start = finish = -1;

for (let word of search)
{
  for (let i in source)
  {
    if (source[i].indexOf(word) !== -1)
    {
      if (start === -1)
      {
        start = finish = i;
      }
      else if (i > finish)
      {
        finish = i;
      }
      else if (i < start)
      {
        start = i;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(start, finish);
```